# How can I determine if a given directory is `symlink`ed to in Python?

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to remove a set of directories, excluding those that are in used and `symlink`ed to elsewhere.

What is the most effective way to determine if a given directory is `symlink`ed to?

I've tried `os.stat(dir).mt_nlink`, but it returns `3` even for directories I want to remove.

**EDIT**:

By `symlinked` to I mean this directory is a target of some symlink.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if file is symlink in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068419/check-if-file-is-symlink-in-python)

Comment: @alko not that one but may be this one [Is there a way to check if there are symbolic links pointing to a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100170/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-there-are-symbolic-links-pointing-to-a-directory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no easy way to determine if someone else has made a link to a given "hard" directory. You can only check if a given directory is a symlink to another directory.

This means that you need to traverse your entire directory structure, look for symlinks, and then check if they point to the directory in question.

A symlink is a special file which points to another file/directory, somewhere in your directory structure. Symlinks can point to other filesystems as well. Creating a symlink does not change the inode of the destination file/folder (as opposed to hard links), so you can't tell by looking at the target, only at the link itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use [os.path.islink(path)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=islink#os.path.islink).

Straight from the docs:

> Return True if path refers to a directory entry that is a symbolic
>   link. Always False if symbolic links are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Use [os.path.islink](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/os.path.html#os.path.islink).

You can also test if a path is a broken link using [os.path.lexists](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/os.path.html#os.path.lexists) (a file is a broken link iff it `lexists() and not exists()`).

Comment: If you already know a path is a symlink, you don't need to call `lexists` to see if it's broken - `not exists(link)` is sufficient.